# Question on tabbing to next NON-READONLY field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

On blur of field1, field2 is set to READONLY but the cursor on my page then defaults to field2 and the cursor is located at the END of the value and when the user clicks the backspace button the value can be erased.  I would like the ability to have the cursor move to the next NON-READONLY or ENABLED field on the page. Is that do-able with jQuery?

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
           $("#ARTransferForm\\:fromAccountAmt").blur(function() {
               var origAccountAmount = $("#ARTransferForm\\:fromAccountAmt").val();
               var fromAccountAmount = $("#ARTransferForm\\:fromAccountAmt").val();
               // Call validation "r2" function            
               var modFromAccountAmount = r2(fromAccountAmount);
               //alert("modFromAccountAmount = " + modFromAccountAmount);
               fromAccountAmount = $("#ARTransferForm\\:fromAccountAmt").val(modFromAccountAmount).val();
               //alert ("modified fromAccountAmount = " + fromAccountAmount);
               if (modFromAccountAmount != "N.aN") {
                   var firstChar = fromAccountAmount.charAt(0);
                   var fromAcctAmtLen = $("#ARTransferForm\\:fromAccountAmt").val().length;
                   if (firstChar == "-") {
                       var revFromAcctAmt = fromAccountAmount.substring(1, fromAcctAmtLen);
                       $("#ARTransferForm\\:toAccountAmt").val(revFromAcctAmt);
                       $("#ARTransferForm\\:toAccountAmt").attr("readonly", "readonly");
                   } else {
                       $("#ARTransferForm\\:toAccountAmt").val("-"+fromAccountAmount);
                       $("#ARTransferForm\\:toAccountAmt").attr("readonly", "readonly");                 
                   }
               } else {
                   $("#ARTransferForm\\:fromAccountAmt").val(origAccountAmount);
                   $("#ARTransferForm\\:fromAccountAmt").select();
                   alert("Invalid From Amount Format. Use ##.## (NO commas or $ sign)");
               }
           });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying tabindexes onblur, before RETURN TRUE, to control where the cursor goes? It's kind of a hack, but there you go.

Also, you could use a delegated event (perhaps on the form) to intercept and return false on any keypress events that would modify the value of any readonly input. Something like:

```
$('#ARTransferForm *[readonly]').live("keypress", function(event) {
    // compare keycode to blacklist: backspace, perhaps delete too?
    if(bKeyIsBlacklisted) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

(Note: that is pretty pseudocodeonous. You'll want to double-check the syntax for sizzle's attribute selectors, as well as jquery's event delegation signature. And be *real* careful about how wide you cast your "no keys" net: try to avoid disallowing Copy and other operations performed with keyboard shortcuts. You will need to check for a modifier key to distinguish between the user trying to type "c" and Ctrl+C.

Which browser(s) are you testing this in?

Comment: I have not tried modifying the tabindexex onblur.  I'm pretty new to jQuery so I'm learning as I go.  I am using only IE8 as this is the only browser supported within our company.  I appreciate your help.